# How to find the version of Jetty used in Restlet framework version 2.1?

Tags: java, jetty, restlet

Need to know the version of Jetty that an application based on Restlet framework uses. All I know is that the version of Restlet framework used is 2.1 from the pom.xml file in the project.

Answer (score 2):

use the "--version" flag:

> java -jar start.jar --version

Answer (score 0):

If you add -X to the build command line it should show the way maven resolves dependencies, giving you a full dependency chain including what version of jetty would be getting pulled in.

Some of the tooling for various IDE's will give you this information as well, if you open the pom.xml in Eclipse with the m2eclipse tooling you should see a pretty graph with this info.